# Matching two words with constant random characters between them

Tags: sed, grep

I am trying to search for a grep command that will allow me to extract two patterns (words) for every line with random sequence in the middle of a specific length (6 in my case):

```
ATCAACGCAGAGTACATXXXXXXGGG
```

Here in my case I have the two words: "ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT" and "GGG" with in the middle 6 letters "XXXXXX" but these can be whatever letter.

I have looked at the already available solution but there is none specific to this one I believe.

**Input**

```
ACGCAACGACGACG**ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT****XXXXXX****GGG**AATTTA
AGGGAACGTTGCCG**ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT****XXXXXX****GGG**CATGGA
GGAACGTTGCCAAG**ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT****XXXXXXXXX****GGG**ATG  (this does not match for example)  
AGGGAACGTTGCCG**ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT****XXXXXX****GGG**CATGGA
```

**Output**

```
ACGCAACGACGACG**ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT****XXXXXX****GGG**AATTTA
AGGGAACGTTGCCG**ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT****XXXXXX****GGG**CATGGA
AGGGAACGTTGCCG**ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT****XXXXXX****GGG**CATGGA
```

where "XXXXXX" can be every combination of A,C,T,G like AATCGA or AAATCC etc..

How could I do this with `grep` or `sed`?

Comment: Are the strings always the same length?

Comment: ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT   and GGG  yes and also XXXXXX  yes

Comment: The Xs can be **any letter**? Like CAACGC? Or CAXXGC? Or should that be none of A,C,G,T? Or six consecutive identical letters like GGGGGG?

Comment: can be A or C or G or T in what ever order. Other letters that are none them can be excluded (am working with DNA)

Comment: Why grep? That does not extract patterns, it only finds whole lines.

Comment: So you mean your data is always 17+6+3 and you need to discard the 6 from every line?

Comment: cat myfile.txt  | grep ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT  | grep GGG   I have all the lines of my file with those two patterns, then from this output I have only to keep lines with the 6 reanodm nucleotides (that can be A or C or T or G) in between them

Comment: What do the STARS mean?? Any sequence, then magic 6, then some more, then GGG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
grep "ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT[ACGT]\{6\}GGG" file
```

Comment: I think `.` would be adequate vs `[ACGT]` since ACGT seem to be the only characters in the OPs data (assuming the `*`s are the OPs attempt to highlight parts of the text, not actually part of the input).

Comment: Or `grep -E 'ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT[XATGC]{6}GGG' dna` for testing, and another regex type.

Comment: I have already tried `.` following a previous post but does not work

Comment: @fusion.slope in what does it "not work"? No output, too much output, error messages, etc.? There's nothing in your question to indicate that `.{6}` (a repetition of any 6 characters) isn't what you need.

Comment: Naked dot with -E: `grep -E 'ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT.{6}GGG' dna`

Comment: @EdMorton I have already tried:  `.` using this command:  `"${ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT}.*${GGG}` from a previous post but grep did not work correctly (meaning that ATCAACGCAGAGTACAT was not extracted. Where did you meant to put `.`, sorry for my incomplete reply

Comment: @fusion.slope `.*` means `any number of characters`, I'm suggesting `.{6}` which means `6 characters`. Try exactly the command in [@rastafile's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568939/matching-two-words-with-constant-random-characters-between-them/568943?noredirect=1#comment1058039_568943). Not sure what you had in mind with `${...}` - that'd be for using shell variables, not literal strings.